# New-AzADUser fails "Insufficient Privileges". Service Account is a User admin in AAD

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to automate the onboarding process at my firm. Get-AZADUser fails with insufficient privileges when running in a user context that has full admin privileges for user objects in AAD. what am I missing?

Comment: Hello @AnthonyC, could you please add the commands that you are using in powershell for the same ?

Comment: Connect-AzaAccount -credential $cred

Comment: Get-AzADUser (any query) returns error insufficient privileges

Comment: Can you please try installing azure ad Module with command 'Install-Module -name AzureAD' and then run Connect-AzureAD and then Get-AzureADUser . Let me know if that works .